# How to set QLabel using setPixmap from pointer QImage *image?

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt-creator, ros

i am trying to run two threads. One is the non-Gui thread and the other one is the GUI thread. Now, when i am trying to put the image in the QLabel using the command
 `imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));`
 then i get an error:**QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread**.

So, to deal with the above mentioned problem. I have declared `QImage *image;` in my header file and i get my image from msg into *image  using `image = new QImage(&(msg->data[0]), msg->width, msg->height, QImage::Format_RGB888);`and then i want to set my image in the **QLabel** from this pointer. But i don't understand, **what format of setPixmap should be used** now. 
The usual code                       `imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));`is not working now as `QImage *image` is pointer of type.

So, basically i am trying to do the following:-

```
QImage *image; //in header file
QLabel *imageLabel: //in header file

image = new QImage(&(msg->data[0]), msg->width, msg->height, QImage::Format_RGB888);
imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(???????));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `*` operator to convert `QImage*` to `QImage&`:

```
imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*image));
```

But if you get the "outside of GUI thread" in your error message, you're trying to set the label's pixmap in the other thread. It's not possible. Aside from QPixmap issue, it is not allowed to use GUI objects outside of GUI thread as well.

Comment: Actually i have declared a function `void SelectionInterface::assignImage()` as a slot function in header file. Then, i want to call this function when a button is pressed. Inside this function, i want to assign `*image` to `imageLabel` by wrtting the code `imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*image));` but when i pressed the button...then nothing happens

Comment: To check whether the fuction is working as a slot function or not....i tried to put some text in the imageLabel when the button is clicked..and it worked. And then in the same funtion, i tried to load some image from my computer and put it in the imageLabel on pressing a button....it did not work. Can't understand why?

Comment: Maybe you should create another question with more detailed explanation. This issue is totally separated from your original question.